# filter or find using lodash to find an object then use the nested array

Tags: json, lodash

I have the following json

```
   {
"records": [
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{
"id": "recoEidAQO7qiu7M9",
"fields": {
"Room": "Exterior",
"img": [
{
"id": "attVi68pAaCpX1fDQ",
"url": "https://dl.airtable.com/7munMtXcSK6WHDtMFEqA_IMG_0877%20New%20paint%20(1024x768).jpg",
"filename": "IMG_0877 New paint (1024x768).jpg",
"size": 566394,
"type": "image/jpeg",
"thumbnails": {
"small": {
"url": "https://dl.airtable.com/uFr8bJcSqyPFoe6n91EA_small_IMG_0877%20New%20paint%20(1024x768).jpg",
"width": 48,
"height": 36
},
"large": {
"url": "https://dl.airtable.com/zfgQJqL7Si2Vi9kZe3Bx_large_IMG_0877%20New%20paint%20(1024x768).jpg",
"width": 512,
"height": 512
}
}
}
]
},
"createdTime": "2016-08-16T21:29:37.000Z"
}
]
}
```

I'm attempting to use lodash. I'm trying get the url for the value 'Exterior' so that with jquery I can concatenate and build the following

```
$('wrapper').css('background-image' , 'url('+url+')')
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of [**find**](https://lodash.com/docs#find) and [**get**](https://lodash.com/docs#get) in order to get the url:

```
var obj = _.find(json.records, function(el) {
  return _.get(el, 'fields.Room') === 'Exterior';
});
var url = _.get(obj, 'fields.img[0].url');
```

```js
var json = {
"records": [
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{
"id": "recoEidAQO7qiu7M9",
"fields": {
"Room": "Exterior",
"img": [
{
"id": "attVi68pAaCpX1fDQ",
"url": "https://dl.airtable.com/7munMtXcSK6WHDtMFEqA_IMG_0877%20New%20paint%20(1024x768).jpg",
"filename": "IMG_0877 New paint (1024x768).jpg",
"size": 566394,
"type": "image/jpeg",
"thumbnails": {
"small": {
"url": "https://dl.airtable.com/uFr8bJcSqyPFoe6n91EA_small_IMG_0877%20New%20paint%20(1024x768).jpg",
"width": 48,
"height": 36
},
"large": {
"url": "https://dl.airtable.com/zfgQJqL7Si2Vi9kZe3Bx_large_IMG_0877%20New%20paint%20(1024x768).jpg",
"width": 512,
"height": 512
}
}
}
]
},
"createdTime": "2016-08-16T21:29:37.000Z"
}
]
};

var obj = _.find(json.records, function(el) {
  return _.get(el, 'fields.Room') === 'Exterior';
});
var url = _.get(obj, 'fields.img[0].url');

console.log(url);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Tholle, I was stuck trying either filter or find. Anyway much appreciated.

Comment: @James No problem! Glad I could help.